# how to 'inline' type cast in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Maybe there is no way to do this, but I thought I would ask.

Let me explain my question with an example. Imagine this as a groovy script:

```
def myMap = [:]
def myMap2 = ["Hello":'World']
myMap.put("example", myMap2)
//now if I try to write this:
myMap.get("example").get("Hello")
//the get("Hello") comes up as an unrecognized method because groovy doesn't know what type of object it is dealing with until run time
//To avoid this I can do this:
def x = (Map) myMap.get("example")
x.get("Hello")
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to typecast the return from `myMap.get('example')` without out making a new variable/new line

[image: See how the second get is unrecognized]

Comment: Have you tried it? It works as you want at the moment: `myMap.get("example").get("Hello")`  returns "World". Once you fix your syntax error anyway

Comment: the above example works for me as well, as @tim_yates said you just need to fix the syntax in 2nd line, you can also retrieve your object using this syntax: `println myMap["example"]["Hello"]`.

Comment: @bitsnaps I don't think you guys understood the question, because I just tried it again. I do not care what the code returns (and I fixed my syntax error). The code runs correctly, but the second get in  `myMap.get("example").get("Hello")` comes up as an unrecognized variable. Again I understand the code will run and execute fine. I just want that `get` to come up as a recognized variable. Please see my attached screenshot

Comment: @tim_yates please see above comment

Comment: I added a picture to illustrate what I am talking about

Comment: @bitsnaps I think what you have as the second part of your comment is the answer I am looking for, if you want to answer so I can accept it

Comment: Intellij doesn't know what you're putting in the map, hence the underline

Comment: @tim_yates you are correct, but if there was a way for me to 'inline' type cast then it would work (for example: `myMap.get("example") as Map.get("Hello")`) obviously that won't work but I was wondering if there was some groovy goodness I was unaware of that can handle this, but its looking like thats not possible. bitsnap's recommendation might be the only way

Comment: The entire point of the question is asking if there is a way to make the grey underline go away without instantiating (and type casting) a separate variable. I already know why its happening as explained in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the issue is related to the parser syntax and the nature of dynamic behavior of Groovy language. I don't think this is related to IntelliJ since GGTS shows the same behavior.

So right - as you said - you can access `Map` using the alternative syntax:

```
println myMap["example"]["Hello"]
```

Another possible way is to use direct access to object's properties:

```
println myMap.example.Hello
```

Hope this help.